# Why is S&LU without a FAQ yet?

Tags: discusión

I just voted to close a question as off topic but I realized that this site has no "custom" FAQ yet. It's still the basic one.

Is there some reason behind this? If there is not actual FAQ, it looks a bit odd to close something as off topic, also because if the OP disagrees, then it's harder to say "because it's our policy/in the FAQ".

Comment: I think the reason is that the mods (speaking at least for myself) have been busy.  We'll try to work on this soon.  Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: @Flimzy What is "ops" for? :P

Comment: Sorry, I meant moderators... guess I have my site lingo mixed up in my head :P

Comment: Reopened and reclosed to get rid of the semi-manual written duplicate text.

Answer (score 4):

I have posted a [proposed site FAQ](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/12).  Please offer your feedback before it is officially published!

Comment: Thanks man, I have indeed been a little busy but I try to get on the minimum. :)