# Seeking site translators

Tags: discusión, idioma-de-la-publicación

Soon it will be important to translate our [new FAQ](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/12) into Spanish.

We've also talked somewhat half-heartedly about translating many of our questions and answers into both Spanish and English.

For this reason, I want to solicit some expert/native Spanish speakers to do some translation for us!

And the best part is, there's no application process!  For the FAQ, if someone would like to simply translate the existing FAQ proposal to Spanish, and edit the question to include the translated version, I'd be very grateful.

For questions and answers, I would encourage anyone with the motivation to start with the [top-voted](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) or [most hits](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits) questions, and translate both questions and answers into both languages.

As a simple matter of convention, I suggest we leave the original language at the top, and add the translation, following a `<hr>`.  For instance:

> English . . .
>
> ---
>
> Español . . .

For anyone with less than 1000 reputation, this is a great way for you to earn new rep (once your edits are approved), and for everyone else, this can be a great way to be involved in the community.  And perhaps most importantly, for everyone this can be a great way to attract new visitors to the site!  Currently the vast majority of our users are strong English speakers, by translating more of our content to Spanish, we can hopefully attract a larger number of Spanish speakers.

Comment: I'll try to contribute! Very opportune btw!

Comment: It sounds like the [Greatest Hits page](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits) might be a [good place to start](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/).

Comment: @jrdioko: Thanks for the suggestion.  Updated.

Comment: @Flimzy I just finished translating a [post](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/559/526), but I had a question. Is it necessary to translate the titles of questions as well, or only the body of the post? Personally I feel it might be overkill to have every title in two languages, but I felt like I ought to ask anyways. :)

Comment: @Miguel: That's a good question.  I don't have a strong opinion.  I don't think any other L&U site translate titles, but I have asked a [meta question](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/198/12) so this community can make its own decision.

Comment: @Miguel: It seems the majority agree with you that dual-language titles is overkill. See [answer here](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/199/12).

Comment: Are you still seeking site translators?

Comment: @Rubén: As long as there is content on the site that is only in English, yes, we are!

Comment: Great! Hopefully somewhere there is something only in English :)

Comment: Are badges included in the content that should/could be translated?

Comment: @Rubén: Currently, no.  For now, just questions and answers.  Work is currently being done to translate the SO UI for the [StackOverflow in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) site. Once that's done, that may open up the possibility to switch to a Spanish UI, along with Spanish badges, here. If you want to help with translation of that, read [this](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/21519/39315).

Comment: Yay! I signed as committer and once in a while take a look to Area 51 to look for that announce.

Answer (score 1):

**I will have no problems to help with the FAQ, but I thin somebody need to fill the white spaces that the FAQ currently have.**

```
Frequently Asked Questions
What kind of questions can I ask here?

Preguntas frecuentes
Que tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?
```

This site is for **meta discussion** about **spanish.stackexchange.com**. Any question relevant to our community is welcome here. For example, things like:

Este sitio es para discutir acerca del idioma español. Preguntas relevantes al nuestra comunidad virtual es bienvenida aquí. Por ejemplo, cosas como:

```
Are questions about _____ on or off topic?
What should our FAQ contain?
How should we **tag** questions about _____?
**What should our elevator pitch be?**
What should our site design look like?
Who should the moderators be?
How do we promote our site?

Son preguntas acerca de _____ fuera de lugar o no?
Que deve de contener nuestra sección de preguntas fecuentes?
Como devemos de **etiquetar** preguntas acerca de _____?
**Cual debe de ser nuestra aspiracion**?
Como tendría que  lucir nuestro sitio web?
Quienes tendrían que ser moderadores?
Como promovemos nuestro sitio?
```

See The 7 Essential Meta Questions for more detail.

Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.

Para mas detalle mira las siguientes 7 preguntas. **#**

Por favor, antes de preguntar asegurate de buscar que tu pregunta no halla sido hecha con anterioridad en nuestro sitio. Esta bien por otra parte, el responder a preguntas hechas por ti. #~#

```
What kind of questions should I not ask here?

Avoid asking questions that have nothing to do with **spanish.stackexchange.com**. This is not a random discussion area, it's a place for improving our community and website **together**.


Que tipo de preguntas no puedo hacer en este sitio **#**

Evita hacer preguntas que nada tienen que ver con el **idioma español**. Este no es un sitio de discusiones al azar, es un lugar **para juntos** mejorar nuestra comunidad y sitio web.
```

What does voting mean here?

Voting here works a bit differently from the main site. **On Meta**, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness. Please don't be concerned if you receive downvotes – members of the community may simply disagree with your bug, feature request, support issue, or the nature of the discussion.
**++** The las bit should be changed for something related to this site and not the whole stackexchange community, I think **++**

Que significado tiene la votación en este sitio? **#**

Aquí los votos funcionan un poco diferente a los votos en nuestro sitio principal. En **spanish.stackexchange.com**, los votos son comúnmente usados para expresarse en favor o en contra, no para expresar la falta de calidad o utilidad en la respuestas o preguntas. No te preocupes si recibes votos negativos - miembros de nuestra comunidad pueden simplemente no acordar o no estar en favor a tu reporte de error, sugerencia, problemas con el soporte, o la naturaleza de la discusión. #

++ La ultima parte de este párrafo tendría que modificarse para que reflejara este sitio web, no Stackexchange en su totalidad. ++

```
Do I have to log in or create an account?

No. Your account exists only on the main website, so when you are **logged** in there, **you are also logged in here**.

++ That don't really seems to answer the question / What if I'm not registered/logged on the main site ? ++
++ How do you translate correctly "logged"? ++

Tengo que registrarme o crear una cuenta?

No. Tu cuenta existe solo en el sitio principal, cuando tu **accedes a tu cuenta** en el sitio principal **automáticamente puedes acceder** a este sitio
++ Esa respuesta ro responde correctamente la pregunta, Que pasa si el usuario no tiene una cuenta en el sitio principal ? ++
++ Bueno, metí una nueva, Como se dice "logged" ? ++
```

- Text in bold should be explained to find a suitable translation
- Texto en negrita necesita ser explicado para encontrar la traducción
  correcta
- `#` Not exact translation
- `#~#` Improvised transaltion or big modification just to make it look ok
- `++` Notes that require clarification on the original text

I will reach the limit If I post here the full translation but I think the FAQ needs a review before been translated

Comment: Actually the white spaces are the questions about users should ask in meta, the gaps must be in blank.

Comment: Now I see, the FAQ related on this question is about the main site, you translated the FAQ of this meta.

Comment: @JoulSauron The FAQ referensed on the question is the FAQ for this site http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/faq not the one for the main site.

Comment: Nope, read again the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's unnecessary to start translating questions. For one, it's a lot of energy spending (that can be used for answers). Secondly, a bit of mystery is good for those who know either of the languages and want to know the other. If you don't know Spanish and don't want to learn it (at least partially), this site is not useful. However if you decide on doing it, translating from English to Spanish is preferable than the converse. I propose instead to make a question that lists resources for translating.
Now, if the OP decides to post in both languages, that is certainly fine.
Also, I support translating the faq.

Comment: I agree that translating into Spanish is much more important than translating into English.

Comment: If the community doesn't think it's valuable to translate questions and answers, I won't push the issue.  It's something I remember being discussed _very early on_ as a "one day we'll get to it" sort of thing. I would encourage you to open a meta question on the topic, and we can decide what effort to put into it. I doubt it will detract much from answering questions, though. As it is, our question volume is _very low_.

Comment: There are answers in Spanish, where the author claims he/she doesn't speak English very well, hence the Spanish. So I think that a question in both languages will attract more valuable answers, and for a native speaker is not a big effort to translate them.