# Should we have both languages in titles?

Tags: discusión

@Miguel has a good question, relating to [post translation](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/196/12):

Should we translate titles into both languages, or keep only the original language?

And if we do have two languages, how should we format them?

*I have posted a number of possible answers below, so they can all be voted up/down. I honestly think some of them are really bad ideas, so hope they will be voted down; so please do so with impunity. :)  And also please provide your own answers, if you have alternate suggestions!*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Use only the original language in the title

This is most consistent with every other L&U site, to my knowledge.

Comment: what do you mean by original language?

Comment: @Theta30: Whichever language the original author used in the title.

Answer (score 1):

### Use both languages

This would only be for questions *that have been translated to both languages*, and would not be a requirement for posting any questions!

The new title would be translated with a separating character, such as:

> How do I say... / Cómo se dice...

Answer (score -3):

### Translate all titles to English

This provides for uniformity.

Answer (score -3):

### Translate all titles to Spanish

This would be a little like the [French](https://french.stackexchange.com/) site, which seems to have a preference (but no rule) for French. Although they don't seem to translate English-language questions/titles to French, so we'd be going a bit further in that regard.