# ¿Pregunta canónica sobre reglas de acentuación?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, preguntas-canónicas

He visto que no tenemos ninguna pregunta canónica sobre las reglas de acentuación. Parece un tema suficientemente importante y básico como para merecer una pregunta canónica. ¿Deberíamos tener una, como por ejemplo [esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/661/24236)?

Comment: Teníamos [una pregunta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/12637) aquí en Meta donde proponer preguntas canónicas para el sitio principal, pero no tengo problema en que se propongan nuevas en preguntas independientes, dado que considero que así las nuevas propuestas tienen más visibilidad. Por mí no hay problema, me parece una buena opción para una pregunta canónica sobre acentuación. Si la gente está de acuerdo la marcamos como tal.

Comment: @Charlie acabo de añadir [esta propuesta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4367/24236) a esa pregunta. En vista de que las nuevas respuestas a esa pregunta aparecen bastante abajo (y que es difícil ver que son nuevas), y dada la poca participación en Meta, sugeriría que las propuestas se hagan en preguntas separadas. Aunque supongo que también sería posible ponerlas allí y anunciarlas en el chat...

Comment: Precisamente porque conozco la baja participación en Meta decía que me parecía bien que las nuevas propuestas se hicieran en preguntas separadas.

Comment: De acuerdo con la canónica. También sería interesante validar si traducimos o no las canónicas. Históricamente se hizo, pero en la prehistoria se votó que no, por lo que recientemente se quitaron estas traducciones que habíamos estado haciendo ([más detalles](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/list-of-existing-canonical-questions-and-the-place-to-propose-that-a-question-be?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment6875_2505)).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' hmm eso es una pena. Por lo que veo, lo que se votó es [no tener los dos idiomas en los títulos de las preguntas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/198/24236). En esa votación no se habla de preguntas canónicas, ni del cuerpo de las preguntas. En particular, no entiendo la motivación de [esta revisión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/revisions/18440/10) que pones como ejemplo..

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming'  Estoy de acuerdo en que deberíamos tener un debate sobre esto: pienso que las preguntas canónicas deberían estar en los dos idiomas para que realmente sirvan como "duplicate target" de todas las futuras pregunrtas sobre el mismo tema, y no solo de la mitad de ellas...

Comment: The referenced question has been marked as canonical as both this question and the proposal in the linked question have received enough upvotes.

Comment: @wimi hay bastantes más revisiones del estilo, mira https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/18348/brazofuerte?tab=activity&sort=revisions Jun 2, 2020. En cualquier caso, son reversibles si decide así.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question to which you link has two answers which seem to me to cover the issue from two directions. One of them addresses the learner who knows how to say the word but not write it, the other addresses the learner who sees a new word written and wants to know how to say it. That covers nearly everything.

The only thing lacking, I feel, is detail about the exceptions but they may be too many to summarise succinctly.

For instance we have this Q&A about *porque* and friends which is marked as canonical.

Comment: One could add all the diacritic accents (the ones used to distinguish two words that are written and pronounced the same, such as *tu* and *tú*). I think there is a manageable number of those. Apart from those, I cannot think of any other exceptions, am I missing something?

Comment: @wimi that was what I meant. I am not expert enough to know how many there are. I think we may have some questions already dealing with special cases. When I get time I may see if I can find some.

Comment: I edited the [first answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/663/24236) and tried to make it as complete as I could. Hopefully I did not miss much.