# Is it good to ask my question in both languages, even if my Spanish is poor?

Tags: discusión

The meta question [Seeking site translators](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196) askes to translate questions into both languages in case they weren't. I was wondering if it would be a good idea to translate my own questions into Spanish, even if my Spanish is really poor. My translation would contain some mistakes or bad formulations, which may be disturbing and may take a long time to be corrected if the question doesn't get much attention.
So can I try to do the translation myself or should I leave it to experienced speakers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is good, for two reasons.

1. The best way to learn any new language is by practicing. And naturally, practicing includes making mistakes.  Further, when you get your question corrected, you will see clearly what mistakes you made, and you can learn *from* your mistakes.
2. The official language of our site is Spanish, so having more content in Spanish helps the site flourish. Our ultimate goal is to attract as many Spanish-language experts as possible. The best Spanish-language experts in the world may not speak English! By asking in Spanish, you allow the best possible experts to answer your question, even if they don't speak (good) English.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't sure if I could use this site for practising this way, but apparently I can.

Comment: Consider that most of the SE sites are in English, and are welcoming to people with poor English.