# Where too localized starts?

Tags: discusión, preguntas-cerradas

Tue question:

["Toma un tiempo" o "lleva un tiempo", ¿qué suena más natural?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3059/1067)

Was unilaterally closed by @JoulSauron (♦) because it is *too personal and localized* to be suitable for the site.

I'm used to the rules of the SE network, but I'm not sure about **how or where to draw the line** between *general* and *too localized* in Spanish SE.

Figuring out the criteria applied by Joul to this question, I'm wondering why the other questions by this same user [cMinor](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1129/cminor) was not closed at this time, because its other questions are related and almost equally *too localized*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the line between *general* and *personal* interest in Spanish SE is very thin. Most of the questions (if not all) of this user are about a document he is translating. Some of his questions are about technical language, which might be useful for other users and welcome here.

However, the question I closed is about how can he improve his sentence in its context, so I don't see how it can be useful to future users. It's true that there were no close votes, but there aren't any reopen votes as well. As a moderator, I only applied the [rules proposed by the community here in meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/new-proposed-site-faq) (not even StackExchange). The rest of the questions of this user that I had not so clear what to do, I let the community decide.

If you think that we should let ask questions about "translating and correcting sentences", you can open a question in meta and let's see what the community thinks.

TL;DR: I closed it because it's asking an opinion about a particular sentence, and I think that it won't be useful for future users.

Comment: I really don't see much difference, for example, with [this other question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/translate-something-that-is-in-a-fashion-way)

Comment: @jachguate I think the difference is that your question is more asking "Which sounds better?" whereas that one is asking, "What sounds more like natural Spanish?" The difference is subtle but important.

Comment: Ok, I get it, many thanks!!